# Alienware X15 R2 Power adaptor

Tags: laptop, gaming, power-supply

I have an Alienware X15 R2. The power adaptor is lost and I'm looking to buy a new one. The Dell corporation does not have the same exact one that came with the laptop. So, I have found the exact charger on their website, which matches all the specs except this thing called "small form factor" (SFF). This is the only difference. I have contacted the Dell tech people but they refuse to give me a proper explanation. Can anyone here tell me if this SFF makes difference or not?